# Showing path of selected files in ListBox

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to see names or paths of selected files in VBA using windows explorer.

Here's what I have done so far, it opens the explorer and allows to select files but lacks displaying the names/path of the files.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
   With fd
      .AllowMultiSelect = True
      .Title = "Please select the file."
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      If .Show = True Then
        ///
        ///here comes the part with showing the names in ListBox
        ///
      End If
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the completed code:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim i As Integer

   Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
   Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With fd
      .AllowMultiSelect = True
      .Title = "Please select the file."
      .Filters.Clear
      .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      If .Show = True Then
         For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
            ListBox1.AddItem fd.SelectedItems(i)
         Next
      End If
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for :)